# Can't use API Management service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

I'm trying to use the "API Management" service on Bluemix, but I have the message "Not fetch data plans".. so I can't use the service

I'm trying to change the country or region, but it's always the same message.
I need help clarifying what causes this problem.

Comment: you're gonna need to provide a little bit more information for us to help

Comment: What steps do you take to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Can you please provide more information to try to help figure out what is going on?

Comment: When I add the API Management Service, I get the message "Not fetch data plans"Then when I try to create, I get the error:
"Request invalid due to parse error: Field: service_plan_guid, Error: Missing field service_plan_guid"

Comment: When do you hit the "Not fetch data plans", is it during the provision time or the APIm Service? Does the tile eventually show up in your dashboard?

Comment: It's at the moment to add the service.  The service never appears on my dashboard.

Comment: Does the service get created using the CLI? (cf create-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with Firefox as the browser and German as content language. The moment I set the language of the browser to English, the plan details on API management appears and I am able to create the service.

Comment: Henning is correct.  This issue is with the translation.  We are currently fixing the issue with the German local, but Cristian...what locale was your browser using?

Comment: I tried Chrome / Spanish / English = problems.
I switched to Safari / English, and the problem was solved
Thanks